# ¿Cómo pasar a setInterval() una función con parámetros?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo un bot con Node.js y quiero que uno de los métodos, **tweetIt()**, se ejecute cada X segundos, para lo que uso el método **setInterval()**.

tweetIt() recibe un array de frases.

Al llamar al método setInterval(), que recibe la función tweetIt(), me encuentro con que me lanza un **error** si a tweetIt() le paso parámetros:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a 
function. Received undefined
```

Si modifico el código para no tener que pasarle la función sin parámetros, funciona.

Resumiendo, la **pregunta** es: ¿cómo puedo pasarle a setInterval() una función con parámetros?

Aquí está el código:

**tweetIt()**

```
function tweetIt(text){
var tweet = {
    status: text
}

T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response){
    if(err){
        console.log("Shit!!");
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("It worked!");
    }
    // console.log(data);
}
}
```

**setInterval()**

```
setInterval(tweetIt(addDevStatuses[randomIndex]), 1000*20);
```

**Array de frases**

```
var addDevStatuses = [
"Frase 1",
"Frase 2",
"Frase 3",
"Frase 4"
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma de usar [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) es la siguiente:

> ```
> let pID = window.setInterval(función, intervaloDeTiempo[, param1, param2, ... , paramN]);
> ```

El problema con lo que estás intentando, es que ejecutas la función que quieres pasar a setInterval y su resultado es lo que intenta ser ejecutado:

```js
function ejecutarLuego(texto) {
  console.log(texto);
  return 1;
}

//lo siguiente no funciona

setInterval(ejecutarLuego('Hola mundo'),1000);

//porque es equivalente a 

let resultado=ejecutarLuego('Hola mundo');
setInterval(resultado,1000);

//lo correcto es:

setInterval(ejecutarLuego, 1000, 'Hola, mundo');
```

Existe también la opción de encerrar la función que quieres ejecutar en otra:

```
setInterval(() => {
  ejecutarLuego('Hola mundo');
},1000);
```

O tener una función que genere otra, usando clausuras:

```
function generarFuncion(...parametros) {
   return function() {
     ejecutarLuego(...[parametros);
   }
}

setTimeout(generarFuncion('Hola, mundo'), 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Opción 1, Usar una función de flecha para configurar la función de callback que requiere `setInterval` y dentro de la función anónima ya se puede llamar la función con parámetros.

```js
var functionWithParams = (message) => console.log(message)

// Opción 1
// setTimeout, igual que setInterval recibe la función a ejecutar
setTimeout(() => functionWithParams("¡Hola mundo! (Función de flecha)"), 500)


// Opción 2
setTimeout(functionWithParams, 500, "¡Hola Mundo! (Func sobrecarga)")
```

La opción 2 es usar la sobrecarga que permite recibir los argumentos, se puede revisar mayor documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval); el `setInterval` puede recibir más de un argumento para la función que va a ejecutar pasándolos como parámetros posterior al **delay**